# Svn checkout of a symbolic link in linux working copy fails with svn: E155009: and svn: E000002: error

Tags: linux, svn, hgsubversion

I have a symbolic link committed into my svn-repository in linux.
When i try to check out the symbolic link i see the below svn error ,

> svn: E155009: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with '/home/mkas0001/test/fram', work item 30 (file-install Versions/Current 1 0 1 1)
>   svn: E000002: Can't create symbolic link '/home/mkas0001/test/fram/Vers/Curr.tmp': No such file or directory

What is the reason behind this error?
I googled and came to know that linux supports svn symbolic link version. A quick and prompt reply will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Manju.

Comment: is the file `/home/mkas0001/test/fram/Vers/Curr.tmp` present in your directory?

Comment: I'll rephrase in case I switched names... is the file your symbolic link is pointing to present in your directory (checked out)?

Comment: Maes, No i fear thats not the case. Actually this was an imported project into svn.For testing purpose i tried to CO the files locally.

Comment: You might look at this svn help page: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html and look for symlink. My guess is that svn tries to recreate the symlink, but since the file does not exist that fails...

Comment: Maes,I just wanted to be clear with the issue. This project which contains the sym link is an exported dump file from perforce.I imported this project into svn,this import worked fine without any errors, Now when i tried to CO the files into a working copy in linux, the co fails. This doesn't happen in case of tortoise svn. Can you please provide some insights into this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't help you any further... I'd suggest you to try with a clean svn repository; try to commit a symbolic link and try to checkout. If that works try removing the originating file and check again if it works...